# Explaning results out of JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, join

I have `mycash` table in MySQL with the following data :

[image: mycash table]

**Test Case 1 :**

When I run the following query,

```
SELECT t.id, SUM(prev.cash) AS cash_sum FROM mycash t JOIN mycash prev ON (t.id > prev.id)
```

I get :

```
id | cash_sum
2  | 1303.00
```

Summing up the `cash` values from all the rows equals to 1302 and **NOT** 1303.

I change the comparison operator in the `ON` condition and get the following results:

**Test Case 2 :**

For `ON (t.id < prev.id)` , result is:

```
id | cash_sum
1  | 2603.00
```

**Test Case 3 :**

For `ON (t.id >= prev.id)` , result is:

```
id | cash_sum
1  | 2605.00
```

**Test Case 4 :**

For `ON (t.id <= prev.id)` , result is:

```
id | cash_sum
1  | 3905.00
```

What is the calculation behind each of the results? Step by step explanation would clarify them most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got the answer my self. It is quite simple.

For any comparison operator in the `ON` condition, we have to compare each row in `table t` with all other rows in `table prev`. The query in any case will output the sum total of all the `cash` values from all the rows (total number of  rows returned may **NOT** be 4 at most).

Let me explain the **test case 1**:

`SELECT t.id, SUM(prev.cash) AS cash_sum FROM mycash t JOIN mycash prev ON (t.id > prev.id)`

We have to select those rows from `table prev` whose `id` numbers are less then a particular `id` in `table t`.

From the first table, i.e. `table t`, when the `id` number is 1, we get no corresponding rows from second table, i.e. `table prev`. When the `id` is 2  from 1st table, we have the `id` 1 (cash =200) from 2nd table. If the `id` is 3 from 1st table, we have 1 and 2 (cash =200 and 301 respectively) from 2nd table. When the `id` is 4 from first table, we have `id`s 1,2,3 (cash = 200,301,101 respectively). So after adding all the `cash` values, `cash_sum` becomes 200+200+301+200+301+101 = 1303.

Other test cases can be explained in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

The results are correct.

[image]

200 + 200 + 200 + 301 + 301 + 101 = 1303